# Auto detection and reading file from USB on QT/linux

Tags: linux, qt, usb

I need to detect the USB device when it is plugged onto the system and read the file a QT application.

a. I have browsed aound and udev is used for Hotplug devices on linux. I played around with the rules in /etc/rules.d/ and figured I could call a script to run when a USB device is plugged in. Some links also mentioned that it can be used to send a dbus signal and i think this will be a btter way than calling a script. It is suggested to use it with HAL and HAL seems to be deprecated and I currently linux version 2.6.34 and QT 4.7. I do not want to use HAL and want to still use the dbus signal. 
I played with the rules like below.

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd[a-z]*", RUN+= "/opt/test.sh"
```

I would like to use these rules to send the dbus signal like

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd[a-z]*", RUN+="/bin/dbus-send --session --type=signal dbustest.helloworld"
```

which does not work. Am I missing something or any pointer would be helpful.

b. Please suggest pointers for reading a file from the USB using the QT application. I have looked up libusb but I do not want to add a new lib on my existing target .

Any help/pointers will be greatly appreciated.
thank  you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I detect usb drive insertion in Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190542/how-do-i-detect-usb-drive-insertion-in-linux)

Comment: Also, `udisks2` will post a `MountAdded` event on dbus, which you can receive in the QT application. To read files you just read them from where the disk was mounted, it's a regular file system.