# Kernel Module which opens a script when inserting an USB-Stick

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module, usb-drive

I need to write a Kernel-Module which do something like open a script when an USB-Stick got inserted. I can't find any Header-File or smth i can use to check, if a USB-Stick got inserted, not first time initialized. I found a function for disconnects, but not for connects but the disconnect function also doesn't work because the usbhid is Blocking it (I think so, I'm not sure). Tried to unload the Driver but doesn't helped. Did anyone know where I can find a function for USB-Connection? Or send me a code example? I don't mean probe functions!

Thank you community

Comment: Why not just write an udev script?

Comment: I already did, also a Perl script which is listening on syslog. But I really want a Kernel Modul for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider adding a Udev [rule](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/udev). Writing a kernel module is not good option as its not a good idea to run scripts in Kernel mode, Kernel mode is not intended to do that.

There is an answered question [How to do I detect USB drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190542/how-do-i-detect-usb-drive-insertion-in-linux)

Comment: ok, could you pls explain how I have to create the udev rule and how it looks like? I never used udev

Comment: I just found some examples where I have to hand over the Vendor an Product ID but I want the rule for all USB Sticks

Comment: Doesn't matter anymore, will use the Perl script for that. But thx for your help